# How to pass object in constructor Angular?

Tags: angular

I have own class with dependency:

```
export class PeriodClass {

public constructor(
  private educationPeriodService: EducationPeriodService){}
}
```

I use this class in component:

```
@Component({
  providers: [PeriodClass]
});

class ComponentClass {
  public constructor(public classPeriod: PeriodClass) {
  }
}
```

It gives me an error:

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for PeriodClass: (?, ?).

Cause when I inject `PeriodClass` in component I dont pass dependency `EducationPeriodService`, how to?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To inject a class/Service to component, make sure it is:

1. marked as `@Injectable()`
2. Added to List of Providers in the module/component where it's used.

Answer (score 1):

Add the @Injectable annotation to your PeriodClass.